# java while and for loops dilemma

Tags: java

I m working on this example and I cannot seem to figure what i am doing wrong.

```
public class NestedLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userNum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (j <= userNum) {
            System.out.println(j);
            ++j;
            for (i = j; i <= userNum; ++i) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The result is below. as you can see my result is backward and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried to change the variables all around and I am not getting any where. any help will be greatly appreciate.

```
Expected output:
0
 1
  2
   3
Your output:
0
   1
  2
 3
```

Thanks

Comment: Your loops are simply weird. Think of ways to make it easier with a number of concatenated blanks.

Comment: Not related to your question but that return statement is superfluous

Comment: Is `userNum` always 0?

Comment: *"The result is below."* No this is a different result. The result of this code is always `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `userNum` to increment which is wrong and increment `j++` after spaces return. You can also remove the return statement.

Corrected code:

```
public class NestedLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userNum = 3;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (j <= userNum) {
            System.out.println(j);
            for (i = 0 ; i <= j; ++i) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop you want to print `j` spaces followed by `j`:

```
while (j <= userNum) {
    for (i = 1; i <= j; ++i) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(j);
    ++j;
}
```